# Evaluate function reversing order of integration.

Tags: calculus

> To Find:

$$\int_0^1\int_{4x}^4 e^{-y^2} dydx$$

> I have:

$$0\le y\le4$$ $$0\le x \le \frac{y}{4}$$

$$=\int_0^4\int_{0}^\frac{y}{4}e^{-y^2} dxdy$$

$$=\int_0^4\left.e^{-y^2}x\right|_0^\frac{y}{4}\,dy$$

$$=\int_0^4\frac{y}{4}e^{-y^2}\,dy$$

> where to from here?

Comment: Answered down below, make sure you ask something if you do not understand it and also make sure to approve the answer if it's the one that fits you so the thread comes down as "asnwered".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is : $\int_0^4 \frac{y}{4} e^{-y^2} = \frac{1}{4} \int_0^4 ye^{-y^2}  $

For that, substitute  $u = -y^2 $ and $du = = -2ydy$. ($u_1 = 0, u_2 =-16$)

You get the integral : $ -\frac{1}{8} \int_0^{-16} e^udu = -\frac{1}{8}  \left[e^u\right]_0^{-16} = \frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{8 e^{16}}$